# How do I use a convention to specify the Foreign Key and the Primary Key should be the same column on a Joined Subclass table?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, automapper, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Title pretty much says it all.  If I have 2 classes:

```
public class Account
{
    public virtual Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class VendorAccount : Account
{
    public virtual string TaxId { get; set; }
}
```

How would I use a convention to create the VendorAccount table like so (or some approximation):

```
create table VendorAccount
(
    AccountId uuid not null primary key references Account (AccountId),
    TaxId varchar
);
```

I have been fussing at this for days.  `IJoinedSubclassConvention` and `ISubclassConvention` do not allow you to specify the Id, and all other conventions can't seem to reach this situation either.

The closest I have gotten will make a column `account_id`, which is not what I want.

Comment: Since you have a class hierarchy, are you using table per class hierarchy or table per subclass?

Comment: @RussCam I am not clear on the difference, I guess.  I am expecting the base class to have a table, and the subclass to have a table essentially "extending" the base class.

Comment: Fluent NHibernate defaults to using table-per-subclass strategy - https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Automapping-inheritance (see Configuring the subclassing strategy section) so you will have separate tables for `Account` and `VendorAccount`. You could provide some overrides to the automapping -https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping or if you don't have that many entities, you could write the mappings for more control.

Comment: Why does the primary key of `VendorAccount` need to reference the `AccountId` field (presumably the primary key) on `Account` i.e. what is the problem that you are trying to solve? There may be a better way of doing it with fluent NHibernate. Could you also post the mapping that you have so far?

Comment: @RussCam From a database perspective, this is nice and efficient... the primary key of the subclass will always reference exactly one primary key on the parent class table.  I had assumed that was how inheritance was supposed to work in NHibernate.

Comment: I've never seen that kind of configuration in a class hierarchy (that's not to say it's not possible, however the relationship is inherited from a class perspective). It sounds like the table per class hierarchy might be a better fit for what you want to achieve. This means that there would be one table for both classes with fields for the properties of both classes and a discriminator field so that NHibernate knows which type to hydrate in the application when it gets a record. Does that sound like a better fit?

Comment: @RussCam Hmmm... yes it does.  I will look into this and see if this is what I really want to do.

Comment: I think I understand where you are coming from - for a `VendorAccount`, you'd like to store the values for properties that are common with `Account` in the `Account` table and have a separate table for storing values for properties that are only relevant to `VendorAccount`. Is that correct? If so, I don't think this is *easily do-able* when there is inheritance relationship...

Comment: @RussCam yes that is it exactly.

Comment: Correction, *I don't think this is possible* when there is an inheritance relationship (you could split properties for a single type across tables, but the documentation discourages it - http://ayende.com/blog/2327/multi-table-entities-in-nhibernate) the `Account` table would still need a discriminator column to know whether a record represents an `Account` type or a `VendorAccount` type and then if it's a `VendorAccount` type to join to the `VendorAccount` table.